# PHP - How to write an array to a file without any array numbers and arrows?

Tags: php, arrays, file, save

I want to write an array to a file, but instead of looking like this:

```php
array (
  0 => 'Something 1
',
  1 => 'Something 2
',
  2 => 'Something 3
'
)
```

It should look like this:

```
Something 1
Something 2
Something 3
```

Is it possible? I'm currently using this method to write an array to a file:

```php
file_put_contents('array.txt', var_export($array, TRUE));
```

Comment: is this your homework?

Comment: Nope. Why would you ask?

Comment: Many ways, loop over the array and write row-by-row, join all values and write it all at once, etc.

Comment: `file_put_contents($path, $array)`

Comment: Normally it's usually homeworks that requires text files or assignments from school

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing Array to File in php And getting the data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869104/writing-array-to-file-in-php-and-getting-the-data)

Comment: @u_mulder on a side note, while it is actually valid it behaves like `implode('', $array)`, so no new line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very simple method:

```
file_put_contents('array.txt', implode(PHP_EOL, $array_data));
```

Comment: all answers are correct so far but this is the most eloquent answer.

Answer (score 1):

> `var_export()` would simply turn the Array to its String Representation/Equivalent just like What you have up there [The Exact same Array Structure but just as a String DataType]. You may have to simply build the String Output using a Loop and then save the Resulting String. That way, you get the kind of Result you expected. The Snippet below attempts to capture the idea here:

```
    $arr                = array (
        0 => 'Something 1',
        1 => 'Something 2',
        2 => 'Something 3'
    );

    $writableStr        = "";

    foreach($arr as $value){
        $writableStr   .= $value . "\n";
    }

    file_put_contents("array_data.txt", $writableStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the array and write the contents in a string

```
 foreach ($array as $item){
    $str .= $item . '\n';
 }

 file_put_contents('array.txt', $str);
```